# Is there a way to tell if a site is based on C# or VB?

Tags: asp.net

I'm putting a quite together for a client, and as usual they don't know anything about their website - he is awaiting details from his (previous) web developer.

In the meantime, I don't have access to the website code.

Is there any way to tell if a .NET site is based on VB or C# with only browser access to a (live) website?

Comment: fortunately no :) The code is running at the server side, not the client side. I said fortunately because this would add some details on the website that may be exploited by a malicious user.

Comment: You could look for things that differ when using the different languages - eg naming conventions. If you've got text boxes called `txt...` everywhere and buttons called `btn...` its more likely that its VB, but you're not going to be sure.

Comment: @JonEgerton: I use this naming convention with C#... very very unreliable way!

Comment: @Darkcat Studios, I do not think that it is possible to determine the language in which the site was written.  Even if you know, what's the difference?  You can always include C# code in VB.NET web app and vise versa...

Comment: @JonEgerton - good idea - i noted that a button is called btnXXX and there is a txtXXXX text box too. Its a long shot, as said BUT its pointing me vaguely towards VB (which is good, as my C# powers are weak)

Comment: No, It is not possible. What will happen if you dont know the language